# Model-theoretic characterization of local modal correspondence

Tags: logic, model-theory, modal-logic

I've been reading van Benthem's dissertation ([available on ILLC's website](https://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Dissertations/reportlist.php?Series=HDS)) on modal correspondence theory.  In Section I.3, he develops a model-theoretic characterization of modal formulas having first-order correspondence.  That is, a modal formula has first-order correspondence iff it is preserved under ultrapower.  His proofs are mainly stated for *global* correspondence and he just states **3.7 Theorem** on *local* correspondence saying "[it] may be proved by using the same methods".

Here's my thought: a (second-order translation of a) modal formula $\phi(x)$ locally corresponds to first-order $\alpha(x)$ iff $\mathrm{Mod}(\phi(c)) = \mathrm{Mod}(\alpha(c))$ in the frame language expanded with a new constant symbol $c$.  If closure under ultra*power* implies closure under ultra*product* (a consequence of an analogue of Goldblatt's lemma **3.1**), as far as  $\mathrm {Mod}(\phi(c))$ is concerned, then **3.7 Theorem** holds.

The original Goldblatt's Lemma embeds an ultra*product* $\prod_i F_i/U$ of frames in the ultra*power* of the disjoint union $\bigoplus_i F_i$ of frames.  Taking a disjoint union makes sense because the original frame language is purely relational.  However, since my new language contains a constant symbol, it is unclear how to adapt the original argument a la Goldblatt.

How can I prove **3.7 Theorem**?

Comment: I believe I figured this out and might write the solution down later.